# How to access to interface or type alias which has not been explicitly exported in TypeScript type definitions?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to create the class inheretid from [Vinyl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl).
The constructor of superclass accepts the single parameter of `ConstructorOptions` type.

```js
export default class MarkupVinylFile extends Vinyl {

  public constructor(options: ConstructorOptions) {
    super(options);
  }

  // ...

}
```

Currently I can't import the `ConstructorOptions` to use it as type annotation. In `vinyl/index.d.ts` is has been declared as:

```js
interface ConstructorOptions {
    cwd?: string | undefined;
    // ...
}
```

It could not be imported as `import Vinyl, { ConstructorOptions } from "vinyl";`.
Is it possible to import the `ConstructorOptions`?

[Vinyl Type Definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/vinyl/index.d.ts)

Comment: `import { ConstructorOptions } from "vinyl";` Does this not work?

Comment: If it is not exported, it can't be imported. But maybe you access the type through some other type that has been exported?

Comment: Could you declare it as an empty interface `interface ConstructorOptions {}`? It would later be merged. This is kind of like a C++ forward declaration. Issue #31894 on the Typescript repository seems to have rejected more explicit functionality for this, unfortunately.

Comment: @MikeS. Yes. If try to import as `import { ConstructorOptions } from "vinyl";`, the error `TS2305: Module '"vinyl"' has no exported member 'ConstructorOptions'.` will occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As implied by @TobiasS. in the question comments, you can indirectly refer to this type.

Here we can use the [`ConstructorParameters`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#constructorparameterstype) built-in utility type for this purpose:

> Constructs a tuple or array type from the types of a constructor function type.

```
// The vinyl types merge a variable, an interface and a namespace,
// so to get the "class", we have to tell TS to target the variable with `typeof`
type ConstructorOptions = ConstructorParameters<typeof Vinyl>[0];
//   ^? type ConstructorOptions = ConstructorOptions | undefined

// Alternatively, in case there are more than 1 argument,
// we could have used a rest operator with the full tuple:
export default class MarkupVinylFile extends Vinyl {

  public constructor(...args: ConstructorParameters<typeof Vinyl>) {
    super(...args);
  }

  // ...

}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

That being said, if your constructor does nothing else than calling `super()`, you could just omit it.

Note: you should get an error when trying to `extends Vinyl`:

> Base constructors must all have the same return type.(2510)

That is because the vinyl types declare [several constructors with different return types](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/c9e49752511d35c494281a92385add86cfc13538/types/vinyl/index.d.ts#L55-L60).